# Compare two columns same text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Probably simple question:

Have two columns:

```
A containing datetimes formatted as Time e.g : 666:45:23
B containing datetimes (but as Text!)        : 666:45:23
```

From the view perspective all looks the same. Now i would like to put formula to column C and see if there is/not diffrence between two columns A and B. How to do that?

I tried so far =A1=VALUE(B1) but not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert both to text using a time and text number format mask.

```
=TEXT(A1, "[hh]:mm:ss;@")=TEXT(B1, "[hh]:mm:ss;@")
```

[image]